# How to pass .dae into three.js to run on the web browser

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi Guys I am a HTML developer never worked on `WEBGL` thechnology. I go through many sites to understand that how to `.dae` file pass into 'three.js' but i failed to do this.

Please be of help share your knowledge with me of three.js. Is there any basic tutorial which I fail to find plz share.

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: Hi, you can start from here http://threejs.org/, and the downloads are here https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following example on the threejs website: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada

A .dae file is a Collada file type - have a look at the source and you will see how the loader works. Remember to download and include ColladaLoader.js on your page to enable the facility.

Comment: thanks for help @athms is there any detailed tutorial to understand how to run 3d object into webgl..

Comment: @Kamal not that I know of. You can take a look at the source of the link I shared and refer to lines 52 to 65. You will also need to add the object to the scene using scene.add( dae );